# Where can I find the code for drop down menus?

Tags: java, css, internet-explorer-10

I am having an issue where drop down menus aren't re-sizing properly when zooming in (IE10) for this one webpage. There is one user account on the network that works properly, but the others don't, admin or not.

**100%:**

[image]

**125%:**

[image]

**75%:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

I have verified the version on java installed on both and they are the same. Oddly though, the user account that works will break if I uninstall two older versions of java (6 Update 27 & 30) that are also installed there. The menus won't even work when not zoomed. This is odd as these older updates seem to have no effect on another user account I tested.

I have tried compatibility view, and I have reset and reinstalled IE10 on both the working and a non-working account. It didn't fix the one that wasn't working, and it didn't break the one that was working.

So, what I want to know, where can I find the code for the re-sizing of these menus so I can compare it?

Comment: So this is a Java applet that displays a menu bar of some sort? Not some Javascript/CSS/(D)HTML combination? (With a modern web site I would expect the latter, but your question speaks only of Java.) Java *is not* Javascript in *anything* but name.

Comment: I would experiment with the IE compatibility-mode features http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11 .

Comment: I have tried compatibility view, and I have reset and reinstalled IE10 on both the working and a non-working account. It didn't fix the one that wasn't working, and it didn't break the one that was working.

I also added image links

Comment: **You can't see the source.**  Because its neither HTML or Javascript that is offering that menu.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: seek support from the vendor, and perhaps try an alternate browser. keep in mind though, there probably isn't a good answer to your issue, because browser zoom is only for markup content. java interfaces generally implement a layout manager that the developer configures to display their material as they see fit. This functionality can't talk to the browser however.

Comment: Markup content? So you are saying this has nothing to do with the browser and I should seek support from the owners of the webpage? The thing that is confusing to me is why it works on one account but not any others. That would make me think it is not an issue with the code, but, at the same time, I don't know where else to look at this point.

Comment: websites display layout information based on Markup langagues like XHTML, SGML, etc. one of the big benefits of markup languages is that the browser can interpret them differantly based on the client resolution, font settings, etc. this is called reflowing.  Zoom works by reflowing the layout elements and some style elements so that things are bigger. You just can't do that with java.